# How to change UISearchBar Font Size & Color?

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, textcolor

I've google fews hours how to change my UISearchBar font size & color, but I cannot any documents related to it.

This is what I've done so far on swift 4:

```
 searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - (menuImage.frame.width + iconImage.frame.width + 55), height: 30))
 searchBar.placeholder = "SEARCH BAR"
 searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.gray
 searchBar.delegate = self
 searchBar.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Oswald" size:11];
```

but it gave me an error.

Could you tell me how can I change the UISearchBar font size & color?

Please help!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the UISearchBar search text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499701/how-can-i-change-the-uisearchbar-search-text-color)

Comment: oh thanks you so much, it's working well

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To change text and placeholder searchbar:

```
// SearchBar text
let textFieldInsideUISearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
textFieldInsideUISearchBar?.textColor = UIColor.red
textFieldInsideUISearchBar?.font = textFieldInsideUISearchBar?.font?.withSize(12)

// SearchBar placeholder
let labelInsideUISearchBar = textFieldInsideUISearchBar!.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
labelInsideUISearchBar?.textColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's how you can change the font and text color on latest Swift:

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(15), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = attributes
```

Answer (score 7):

In the iOS 13 or newest, the UISearchBar has a property called `searchTextField`. But earlier, we can not use this property.

So, we can extend for UISearchBar:

```
extension UISearchBar {
    var textField: UITextField? {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return self.searchTextField
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            for view in (self.subviews[0]).subviews {
                if let textField = view as? UITextField {
                    return textField
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And use:

```
searchBar.textField?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
```

Comment: It doesn't work in iOS 11. textField is nil

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Appearance proxies to style the `UISearchBar` text and placeholder:

Change placeholder:

```
let placeholderAppearance = UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
placeholderAppearance.font = UIFont(name: "Baskerville", size: 14)
placeholderAppearance.textColor = .red
```

Change search text:

```
let searchTextAppearance = UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
searchTextAppearance.font = UIFont(name: "Baskerville", size: 14)
searchTextAppearance.textColor = .green
```

Comment: this is working for placeholder but not for the user-typed text

Answer (score 1):

```
searchBarOutlet.setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:UIControlState.Normal)
```