# How I may change the fontSize of text in UISearchbar?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 80)
self.searchBar.setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : font], for: .normal)
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Please read [ask], and avoid to drop just a snippet of a code.

Comment: You can try this as reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983497/how-to-change-uisearchbar-font-size-color?rq=1 :)