# How to change text color of PlaceHolder in UISearchBar? (iOS 13)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar, ios13

After looking for updated (*iOS 13*) answers, I didn't find any solutions to this simple problem :
 How to change the **`textColor`** of the placeholder in an **`UISearchBar`** ?

My app doesn't handle **`Light/Dark`** mode. I don't want the system to change my **`UIPlaceHolder`** text color. I want it to be always `white`.

---

```
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "My PlaceHolder")
        attrString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrString.length))
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = attrString
    }
```

I expected this code to work. I thought the new property `searchTextField` would have made it easier to customize my `UISearchBar`.

**EDIT:**

This code kind of works in the `viewDidAppear` method :

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
     searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "My PlaceHolder", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.80)])
 }
```

The issue is that the color is changing when you scroll up and down.

Comment: Hi. Maybe this topic will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499701/how-can-i-change-the-uisearchbar-search-text-color. Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28499827/9048325

Comment: I have already read it. Only 1 answer mention iOS 13, and it's just an extension to access the searchTextField property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already mentioned, your code works only in `viewDidAppear`, which makes the placeholder to flicker from the default gray color to the preferred color.

However, there seem to be a time before `viewDidAppear` (I couldn't figure it out when exactly), to change the placeholder before the view actually appears.

I suppose, this may be connected to how iOS handles light/dark mode and/or an iOS bug.

**The solution I came out with that works around the issue:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let placeholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search",
                                             attributes: [
                                                .foregroundColor: UIColor.white
        ])
        let searchTextField = searchBar.searchTextField

        // Key workaround to be able to set attributedPlaceholder
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholder
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There seem to be no performance and/or other downside to this method.

If anybody else comes with a better approach, feel free to collaborate.

Comment: This. This was the answer I have been looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe you can get rid of the for loop there, DispatchQueue.main will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can set this with `UITextField` `appearance` property. check this line of code

```
 UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Comment: The question was about the placeholder text's color, not the text color itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason why it doesn't work is probably the `searchController.searchBar.searchTextField = nil` you got.

`searchTextField` is a new property for `iOS 13`, which can be done if you only support `>= iOS 13`. If you want to adapt to the previous version of `iOS 13`, you can traverse `UISearchBar` to find `UISearchBarTextField` and directly set the found `UISearchBarTextField`.

The code I looked up is probably like this, I put it in the `Category` of `UIView`.

```
- (UIView *)findChildViewClass:(Class)childViewClass fromView:(UIView *)fromView{
    for (UIView *subView in fromView.subviews) {
        if ([subView isMemberOfClass:childViewClass]) {
            return subView;
        }
        UIView *finalView = [self findChildViewClass:childViewClass fromView:subView];
        if (finalView) {
            return finalView;
        }else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

When used, you can customize a `searchTextField` property to inherit from `UITextField` to save the found value.

```
_searchTextField = (UITextField *)[searchBar findChildViewClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarTextField") fromView: searchBar];
```

This is what I use now, it is working, I hope to be useful to you.